# @types/core-js for a dynamic import of the "core-js/stable"

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, core-js

This is what I do in my `index.js` to avoid delivering polyfills to all my users.

**index.js**

```
const renderApp = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <App
      firebase={firebase}
    />
    ,document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
  );
};

/* ############################ */
/* #### CHECK FOR POLYFILL #### */
/* ############################ */

if (
  'fetch' in window &&
  'Intl' in window &&
  'URL' in window &&
  'Map' in window &&
  'forEach' in NodeList.prototype &&
  'startsWith' in String.prototype &&
  'endsWith' in String.prototype &&
  'includes' in String.prototype &&
  'includes' in Array.prototype &&
  'assign' in Object &&
  'entries' in Object &&
  'keys' in Object
) {
  renderApp();
} else {
  import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "core-js-stable" */
    /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
    'core-js/stable'                          // <---- DYNAMIC IMPORTED "core-js/stable"
  ).then(renderApp);
}
```

But I'm getting the "implicit any type" warning in the dynamic import for the `core-js/stable` package. And since I usually work witht the `--noImplicitAny` flag, my project won't compile like that.

[image]

The weird thing is that I have installed the `@types/core-js package`

[image]

Why is Typescript not finding the types for the core-js package?

**NOTE:** If I import it with a regular `import "core-js/stable"` I do not get this warning/error.

Also, if I dynamic import it only the `core-js` without the `/stable` path, I do not get any warning/error.

Like, this is fine:

```
 import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "core-js-stable" */
    /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
    'core-js'
  ).then(renderApp);
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["./src/*"],
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to get rid of the error/warning.

Got this idea from Typescript docs:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#working-with-other-javascript-libraries

I've created this folder for **ambient declarations** and an `index.d.ts` file

`/types/ambient/index.d.ts`

**index.d.ts**

```
declare module 'core-js/stable';
```

And on `index.tsx` you've got to reference the `d.ts` file that you've created, using triple slash directive.

**index.tsx**

```
/// <reference path="./types/ambient/index.d.ts"/>

(...) OTHER CODE

import(
  /* webpackChunkName: "core-js-stable" */
  /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
    'core-js/stable'
).then(renderApp);
```

Now everything works without errors / warnings.

[image]